# gvNIX `finder geo all` Command not finding "geo field"

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I am trying to  create a map based application following [this tutorial](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app)

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with a table called `outlet` on which I added a POINT column called `location_gps` via SQL:

`SELECT AddGeometryColumn('outlet','location_gps','4210','POINT',2);` . This results in an `outlet` table which looks like:

[image: image of outlet table]

Reverse engineering the database to get a Spring Roo app gives me an `Outlet_Roo_DbManaged.aj` with the field:

[image: Snippet of code]

This field is of type String. So when I run the gvNIX command `finder geo all` I get the message

```
The entity specified, Outlet doesn't have geo fields. Use "field geo" command to add new geo fields on current entity.
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Kind regards,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse engineering add-on doesn't support geometry columns (as it's a original Spring Roo add-on). So, you should push-in this property and modify its definition to support geometry column.

Also, remember to execute the setup-commands of gvNIX geo add-on to include required dependencies in your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. What should the correct definition of the field be in order for the java field to support geometry column?

Comment: The easiest way could be create a proof of concept (a new project) using the gvNIX add-on geo to define the field and copy this definition in your project entity.